# C# XDocument insert data into existing XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following code attempting to exist data into a existing XMl file:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
XElement root = new XElement("facilities");
root.Add(new XElement("FacilityName", "Name Data"));
root.Add(new XElement("FacilityDescription", "Description data"));
root.Add(new XElement("Type", "Type data"));
root.Add(new XElement("IPAddress", "IPAddress data"));
root.Add(new XElement("Port", "Port data"));
doc.Element("facilities").Add(root);
doc.Save(path);
```

the resulting XML code is close to what I want but not correct:

```
<Facilities>
<FacilityName>Name data</FacilityName>
<FacilityDescription>Description data</FacilityDescription>
<Type>IP</Type>
<IPAddress>127.0.0.1</IPAddress>
<Port>80</Port>
</Facilities>

<facilities>
<FacilityName>Name Data2</FacilityName>
<FacilityDescription>Description data</FacilityDescription>
<Type>Type data</Type>
<IPAddress>IPAddress data</IPAddress>
<Port>Port data</Port>
</facilities>

</facilities>
```

I need to insert the data into

**Facilities**
not
**facilities**
but when I change it in my code I get a null exception like it is not found in the file...Why?

Comment: Can yo show how the xml is before you insert into it? Also do both the new item and the one to nest it under are called "facilities"?

Comment: The xml you posted doesn't seem valid because it has two roots. I suggest you also to use the XmlSerializer so you can work with a c# graph in a type safe  manner

Comment: Try something like this : XElement facilities = doc.Descendants("Facilities").FirstOrDefault();
facilities.Add(root);

Comment: can you add the desired XML output you are looking for, the XElement you are trying to insert looks same as the one you loaded from file?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: XElement facilities = doc.Descendants("facilities").FirstOrDefault(); facilities.Add(root);

Comment: That got it, Thanks jdweng